# I need to create an HTML table using Javascript with a weird Google Spreadsheet link. How do I do this?

Tags: javascript, html, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Here is the link:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vT4FtWYHA0bhVipKSIk5dZ1nygeSUWsAnI1e2s32915_J0g8KjQU_XRJ3dk4s2hmYWlkddtg-ZM2kXJ/pubhtml?gid=89211736&single=true&widget=false&headers=false

I cannot use anything other than html or javascript.

I know how to do this from a regular shareable link, but this is some sort of api link. I'm not sure. But this link doesn't allow me to do it the easy way. :(

Here is what I have tried

```
<body onload="doStuff()">

    <div id="content">


    </div>



    <script type="text/javascript">

    function doStuff(){

        $.ajax({
            url:'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vT4FtWYHA0bhVipKSIk5dZ1nygeSUWsAnI1e2s32915_J0g8KjQU_XRJ3dk4s2hmYWlkddtg-ZM2kXJ/pubhtml?gid=89211736&single=true&widget=false&headers=false',
            type:'GET',
            success: function(data){
            $('#content').html($(data).find('#waffle').html());
        }
        });

    }

    </script>

</body>
```

Comment: Maybe you could load the url as a string and retrive the table, the document already contains? Keep in mind that this will conflict with CORS

Comment: how would i only target the table tag

Answer (score 0):

If you want to only use JavaScript you need to use Sheets API and follow the quickstart to be able to make requests[1]. You could do a spreadsheets.values.batchGet request [2] to retrieve the values you want, then you can manipulate the html DOM with JS functions like appendchild() [3] to create your html table [4] with the values you retrieve before.

[1] https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/js

[2] https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchGet

[3] https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp

[4] https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Tables/Basics